# How can I add an element after another element?

Tags: html, jquery, append, insertafter

I have a certain textbox and I want to add a div after it.
I've tried the `.append()` function, but that only adds the div in the element.

For example, I have:

```
<input type="text" id="bla" />
```

and I want to change that into:

```
<input type="text" id="bla" /><div id="space"></div>
```

Answer (score 364, accepted):

try using the `after()` method:

```
$('#bla').after('<div id="space"></div>');
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: The .after() and .insertAfter() methods perform the same task.

Comment: That's correct, but it depends on the way you prefer to code it. I'd normally have the '#bla' input selected already, and then add the extra content afterwards. Purely my preference though, I'm not sure whether either method has a speed benefit.

Answer (score 42):

try

```
.insertAfter()
```

here

```
$(content).insertAfter('#bla');
```

Comment: Shouldn't your code be more like `$('<div id="space"></div>').insertAfter('#bla')` rather than `$('#bla').insertAfter(content);`?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, `input` element shouldn't have a closing tag (from http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT : End tag: forbidden
).

Second thing, you need the [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), not `append()` function.

Comment: Correct, but that's what happens when I try the .append() function.

Comment: If it's XHTML then the input element should be closed (but not with an end tag).

Comment: In HTML4 `<input>` should not be closed.

Answer (score -5):

**Solved jQuery: Add element after another element**

```
<script>
$( "p" ).after( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery ( ".sidebar_cart" ) .insertAfter( "<a href='http://#'>Continue Shopping</a>" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This appends the element within the parent element, just like the OP stated. Consider reading the question again and revising your answer.

Comment: Solved 100%  try using the after() method: