# jQuery add next to (add after)

Tags: jquery

HTML is
`<a>ref</a>`

I need to get
`<a>ref</a>text`

How can i do this? `$('a').append('text')` only insert text into `<a></a>`, not after it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Add element after another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244605/jquery-add-element-after-another-element)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$('a').after('text');
$('text').insertAfter('a');
```

Comment: I try this: `$( "#hoa_maintenance_fee_value" ).after('select');` and it adds 12 new select dropdowns within the parent element. Is there a way to make it put just the one select box only after the target sibling?

Answer (score 6):

```
$('a').after("text");
```

Comment: .insertAfter() would try to insert 'a' after "text". Do the inverse, or use .after().

Answer (score 4):

Using the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Content can be created and then inserted after several elements at once:

```
$('.inner').after('<p>Test</p>');
```

Each inner  element gets this new content:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

An element in the DOM can also be selected and inserted after another element:

```
$('.container').after($('h2'));
```

If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be moved rather than cloned:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
<h2>Greetings</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `.insertAfter()` or `.after()`

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('').insertAfter('class name or content string') ;
```