# Append new tag to <div> after a specific element?

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" />
   <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-0"></i>
</div>
```

My question is: How to append

```
<img src="/images/img01.png" />
```

to the `<div>` with position:

```
<div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" />
   <img src="/images/img01.png" />
   <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
</div>
```

via jQuery?

Comment: Have you made at least ***little*** research? There's, you know, such thing as Google.

Comment: `.insertAfter` and `.after` are different from `.append()`

Comment: Okay, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244605/jquery-add-element-after-another-element.

Comment: [Is it really so difficult?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MDhu8.png)

Comment: @nicael ya. I think it's : How to append new tag to div tag with specific position/index? (too long for google search :))

Comment: There's such thing as "rephrasing" your thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```js
$("div input.form-control").after("<img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97100&w=200&h=100' />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" />
   <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-0"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.insertAfter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/):

```
$('<img src="/images/img01.png" />').insertAfter('div input.form-control');
```