# How to change div order in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the div order through JavaScript. i didn't know how to do that

This is the two div which implement in html, but i want  div **id="navigation"** show in html after div **class="row subheader"**.

```
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="item" style="display:inline;">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="display:inline;">Blog: Kannu</div>
</div>

<div class="row subheader">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="blogsubheader">My Blog</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want like this from javascript please check follow.

```
<div class="row subheader">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="blogsubheader">My Blog</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="navigation">
  <div class="item" style="display:inline;">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="display:inline;">Blog: Kannu</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you want to achieve? why you need js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Add element after another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244605/jquery-add-element-after-another-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, then use this :

```js
$('#navigation').insertAfter( ".container" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
            <div class="item" style="display:inline;">
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
           </div>
    <div class="item" style="display:inline;">Blog: Kannu</div>
 </div>


  <div class="row subheader">
  <div class="container">
   <div id="blogsubheader">My Blog</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you want to change the DOM. First you need to clone the first section and store it in a variable. Then remove the first element from the DOM. And append this element after the 2nd element.

To do so using jQuery

```
var nav = $('#navigation').clone(true);

$('#navigation').remove();
nav.insertAfter('.subheader');
```

In JavaScript

```
var nav = document.getElementById('navigation');
var subHeader = document.getElementsByClassName('subheader');

subHeader[0].after(nav);
```

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/moshiuramit/xm85h29g/7/

Comment: Note: This will remove event handlers from the elements you clone. Use `clone(true)` if there are any events bound to it. Also you don't need to clone subheader.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var navigation = document.getElementById('navigation');
var rowSubheader = document.getElementById('row-subheader');

rowSubheader.after(navigation);
```

You'll have to add an id here though, as I did:

```
<div class="row subheader" id="row-subheader">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zmve7xyc/

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the order just for the view consider using [Flex css property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp) (after checking browser compatibility). DOM manipulation is an intensive operation and you shouldn't do it until absolute necessity.

Simply wrap both div in a wrapper div and toggle class for changing flex-direction of wrapper div

Answer (score 0):

You can use *appendTo* also in JQuery.

Ex :

```
var nav = $('#navigation').clone(true);
$('#navigation').remove();
nav.appendTo('.subheader');
```